# How can I create a div in CSS which extends past parents limit but does not resize the parent div?

Tags: html, css

so right now I am trying to implement some kind of search bar with a preview attached to it which shows results as the user is typing.

This preview should be visible right under the search bar. However, this is the current state and this is certainly not what I want:

[image]

As you can see, there is a black navbar above the white content beneath. The navbar should only be as high as the blue botton next to the search field.

So, what I would like to do, is take the preview box and make sure that the parent div does not extend to the size which the preview dropdown requires, but rather have the preview div overflowing into the white content part below.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

My initial idea, which also works considering I created the picture above with this, would be to attach the preview div with `position: absolute` and positioning it dynamically with JavaScript, but this is not quite what I was looking for. In this case I would really love a pure CSS solution to this problem.

Is there anything which could work here?

Comment: This is a simple problem that depends heavily on your markup. You should include a code sample in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, forget about this. I should spend some more time thinking before posting here.

The solution is to simply decorate the div with a negative margin-bottom.

Comment: you simply need a fixed height, not a negative margin